# Post content either behind menu or bleeding in background

Tags: css

I have a problem regarding the position of my table. When I use the following CSS,  I get this result:

```
.page-id-309 .site-content {
margin-top: -70px;
position: relative;
}
```

[image]

But when I try to fix the CSS margins, I get this result

```html
.page-id-309 .site-content {
 margin-top: -70px;
 position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 }
```

[image]

My background is set at

```
.site {
background-color: #fff;
max-width: 80%;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}
```

And I simply can't figure out how to keep my page content proportional depending on the screen size (I don't have this issue on a huge screen, but I do on a laptop monitor.

Edit (code of the table)

```html
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
 if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
  // Include the featured content template.
  get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
 }
?>
 <div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <section id="main_navigation" class="list">
 
</section>

             <div class="container"> 

<table id="tbl" border="10">
<thead>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:3px">Name</td>
<td style="padding-left:3px">Created By</td>
<td style="padding-left:3px">Credit Cost </td>
<td style="padding-left:3px">Invited <br>Candidates</td>
<td style="padding-left:3px">Completed <br>Candidates</td>
<td style="padding-left:3px">Added Date</td>
<td colspan="3">Management</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<a href="/create-project"><input type="button" value="Create a new project"/></a>


  </div>
  </div><!-- #content -->
 </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->
```

Comment: can you please provide an full code to see exactly what are you facing ?

Comment: I added the full code of the page, which is a custom page template (without the php populating the table)

Comment: `I simply can't figure out how to keep my page content proportional depending on the screen size`  Check Media Queries : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

your issue seems to be the with of your table, making flow behind your menu when you try to adjust it. What you have to to is make the with thinner:

1. Break the line on the credit cost table and make the buttons thinner
2. Use zoom property to make it smaller (thus thinner) - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp
3. Use overflow scroll on x-axis (put the table iside a div and give it overflow-x: scroll